# What Open Source GIS tools do you use / recommend?

Tags: open-source, gis

I'm researching Open Source GIS resources - and wonder out of all the Open Source tools that are out there - what people are actually using / finding useful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIS_software

Comment: /generic-should-be-community-wiki-comment/

Answer (score 11):

Here's a few I use regularly

- [postgis](http://www.refractions.net/products/postgis/)
- [gdal](https://gdal.org/)
- [mapserver](https://mapserver.org/)
- [uDig](http://udig.refractions.net/)
- [grass](https://web.archive.org/web/20140528101708/http://grass.itc.it/)
- [geos](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/)
- [geoserver](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430085420/http://geoserver.org:80/display/GEOS/Welcome)
- [gmt](https://web.archive.org/web/20220113032554/http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/)
- [openlayers](https://openlayers.org/)
- [tilecache](http://tilecache.org/)
- [qgis](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/)

Big list here http://opensourcegis.org/

Answer (score 3):

http://sharpmap.codeplex.com for the .Net world. We're not under OSGeo, so you won't find us there.

Comment: how does it compare with OSGeo products?

Answer (score 2):

Here are other resources:

- [Comparison of GIS software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GIS_software) in Wikipedia
- [An Overview of Free & Open Source Desktop GIS (FOS-GIS)](http://www.spatialserver.net/osgis/)

As [MarkJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15639/markj) pointed, [OSGeo.org](http://www.osgeo.org) is a must-check place as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have found Quantum GIS to be quite useful:

http://qgis.org/en/about-qgis.html

Answer (score 1):

Another big list: [OSGeo](http://www.osgeo.org/) is a collaboration to support open source geospatial software.