# Need help choosing an open source GIS

Tags: java, web-applications, open-source, gis

I need an open source GIS that allows one to view/zoom/click the maps using a web browser and should be java compliant (deployable on a java app server).

Well, I have tried to structure the requirement in 'what-i-have' and 'what-i-need' lists:

**Inputs:**
Location: lat/long
Data : Text to display
zoom level: (assume there are about 5)

**Output**
Data displayed on a Map

Would appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks.

`UPDATE: GeoServer + OpenLayers seems to be the best fit for this requirement`

Comment: Can't you use Google Maps API for your requirements? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/

Comment: well, the client policy doesn't allow this. Good suggestion though.

Comment: You might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324976/what-open-source-gis-tools-do-you-use-recommend

Comment: @MarkJ: Yes I did see that, however, my question is a bit more specific. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoServer: http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome

...is what I use.  You have work ahead of you no matter what you pick, though.  Setting up data sources and making them look nice is a decent amount of effort.

Comment: +1. MapServer is also a good alternative to GeoServer http://mapserver.org/

Answer (score 4):

For the client side, [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/) is an excellent Javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the geoserver response and all the rest of the responses ignore your statement that is has to work with Java. The only other bad option would be to write something yourself using geotools.

Go to the OpenGeo site and see the stack they support. That is the stack you are probably most interested in deploying.

Comment: +1 for helping me make sense of the answers quickly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need:

1. [GDAL/OGR](http://gdal.org) to translate the data into a kml file [example](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet)
2. Take that KML file and pump it into either:

   a. Google maps api or openlayers

   b. I've had lots of luck using [featuresever](http://featureserver.org/) which I personally recommend